# Ubuntu - apply patch to kernel sources

Tags: ubuntu, path, linux-kernel

I try to install Ubuntu real time kernel 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945991/ubuntu-install-real-time-linux?noredirect=1#comment92800119_52945991
and I have a problem with (I think) patch. When I run `sudo make install` I have the following problem

```
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.14.71-rt44: No such file or directory
```

In `/lib/modules/` I have only `4.15.0-29-generic  4.15.0-36-generic`.
To install real-time kernel we need `linux-4.14.71.tar.xz and patch-4.14.71-rt44.patch.xz` (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52945991/ubuntu-install-real-time-linux?noredirect=1#comment92800119_52945991). The question is how to move or/and unpack `patch-4.14.71-rt44.patch.xz` to `/lib/modules/` to run 
installation?

Comment: The linked question is now deleted. It's by the same OP and refers to instructions in https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup

Answer (score 0):

[The instructions](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/realtime/documentation/howto/applications/preemptrt_setup) direct you to find the corresponding `PREEMPT_RT` patch for your particular kernel version from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/rt/

There simply doesn't seem to be one for 4.15 so the easiest solution is to pick a version for which there *is* a patch. The first one higher than 4.15 with a patch is 4.16, or you can go back to 4.14, or you can pick the newest available patch (currently 4.19) depending on what exactly you hope to accomplish.

You can fiddle around with the patch to try to get it to apply in a different version than the one you have, but this is unlikely to succeed. Even if the patch applies cleanly, there is no guarantee that the kernel's behavior hasn't changed in one of the crucial kernel services it depends on. Especially if you are only just getting started, reduce the number of free variables as much as you can -- don't go into uncharted territory if you don't have to.